# emacs interactive language buffer (e.g. IPython) how to prevent echoing of masses of text?

Tags: emacs

The echoing is very slow. 
Would it be good for emacs to truncate strings greater than certain number of chars?

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is comint-mode, where the (I)Python shell is built upon. For these cases of very large output python-mode.el offers a way to avoid comint-mode, see `py-fast-process-p`.

Comment: how could i disable this? how could i prevent echoing masses of text?